# How can I provide a test implementation for a "provided" dependency

Tags: maven

I am building a utility that has a provided dependency on Google collections.

I definitely do not want that to be a compile dependency or even a runtime dependency, because there is only one special method that uses that, and I don't want to lock users in to that version of Google collections if they are not using my method.

The challenge is, that since this dependency is provided, how can I build a unit test that tests it?

If I specify a runtime dependency, that will require users to provide my  version of Google collections, even if they don't need it (I am using Table, a new feature).

If I use profiles, I am concerned I am not testing exactly what I am building.

Is there any kind of Maven scope that combines provided and test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking, but the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) says:

> **provided**
>
> This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK
>   or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when
>   building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would
>   set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to
>   scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This
>   **scope is only available on the** compilation and **test classpath**, and is
>   not transitive.